# How to avoid android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb has already been added

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Hil all,

this my error :

```
 Error:Class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb has already
 been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
```

and my dependecies are :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/paralloidviews.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr250-api-1.0.jar')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':Forecast')
    compile project(':headerListView')
    compile project(':library-sliding-menu')
    compile files('libs/panoramagl.jar')
    compile project(':paymentKit_lib')
    compile project(':ProgressWheel-master')
      compile project(':UIL_library')
    compile files('libs/coverflowlibrary.jar')

}
```

so where I could find the duplacte copies, can you help me please, I struggle with this error a long time ago !

Comment: Is **support-v4.jar** inside your **libs** folder also?

Comment: no I don't had support-v4.jar

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably happening because one of your library projects already contains support-v4. Try to remove compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0') from your dependencies and check. This should solve the problem

Comment: even I removed I had that error **Error:Class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.**

thank's for your replay !

Comment: Can you please help me ? or ask any one you tought that's he could help me ?

Comment: There is no other reason for this to happen, even I have faced similar problems while integrating some libraries. The reason is one or more of the libraries already have support v4 and you are additionally adding it to your project. If you remove support v4 dependency from your project and the same msg is being shown that means two or more other libraries have it. You will have to manually check which libraries have support v4 and make sure its used only once

Comment: Yes I checked I found that more than lib has support v4 but when I removed it, and I execut they come back with size=0 (empty file), it's awkward ..